# .tag is not working when trying to segue 3 possible values in Swift 4

Tags: ios, tags, swift4, prepared-statement, segue

I need to segue 3 possible values between the view controllers depending on whatever FIRE BUTTON the user selects. I can transfer one value but I can only transfer one value. I tried to use .tag to get the correct value transferred but it is not working. I think it is clear what I am trying to do. I can not transfer 3 possible values right now.

```
let FIRE = UIButton()
let FIRE2 = UIButton()
let FIRE3 = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    view.addSubview(FIRE)

    let image = UIImage(named: "a.png") as UIImage?
    FIRE.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    FIRE.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
    FIRE.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    FIRE.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      FIRE.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegisterb), for: .allTouchEvents)



    view.addSubview(FIRE2)

    let image2 = UIImage(named: "b.png") as UIImage?
    FIRE2.setImage(image2, for: .normal)
    FIRE2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    FIRE2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
    FIRE2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    FIRE2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    FIRE2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    FIRE2.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegisterb), for: .allTouchEvents)

    view.addSubview(FIRE3)

    let image3 = UIImage(named: "c.png") as UIImage?
    FIRE3.setImage(image3, for: .normal)
    FIRE3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    FIRE3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 600).isActive = true
    FIRE3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    FIRE3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    FIRE3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    FIRE3.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegisterb), for: .allTouchEvents)

}

@objc func handleRegisterb(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: self)
   FIRE.tag = 1
}

@objc func handleRegisterb2(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: self)
    FIRE.tag = 2
}

@objc func handleRegisterb3(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: self)
    FIRE.tag = 3
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "beg") {


        if FIRE.tag == 1 {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.score = "a"

        }


        if FIRE.tag == 2 {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.score = "b"

        }
        if FIRE.tag == 3 {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.score = "c"

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the selected tag in `performSegue` method as part of `sender`,

```
@objc func handleRegisterb(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: 1)
}

@objc func handleRegisterb2(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: 2)
}

@objc func handleRegisterb3(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: 3)
}
```

Then in `prepare` method based on the tag value assign the `score`,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "beg") {
        let tag = sender as! Int
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController

        if tag == 1 {
            vc.score = "a"
        } else if tag == 2 {
             vc.score = "b"
        } else if tag == 3 {
             vc.score = "c"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 action like this , and set the tags for the buttons as 0,1,2

```
@objc func forAll(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender:sender.tag)
}
```

then

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "beg") {
         let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
          let arr = ["a","b","c"] 
          vc.score = arr[sender as! Int] 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same function on all the buttons `handleRegisterb`

each button must be assigned its function (e.x.):

```
FIRE.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegisterb), for: .allTouchEvents)
 FIRE2.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegisterb2), for: .allTouchEvents)
 FIRE3.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegisterb3), for: .allTouchEvents)
```

and in all functions need to assign `FIRE.tag` before calling `performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: self)` function  (e.x.):

```
@objc func handleRegisterb(sender: UIButton) {
    FIRE.tag = 1
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "beg", sender: self)
}
```